# Waveshare LCD1602 display scrolling text on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, lcd

I'm trying to scroll text on the Waveshare LCD1602 display (16x2).
I've uploaded the LCD1602 library [here](https://github.com/omar-ebrahim/WaveShare1602_Python/blob/main/Raspberry/RGB1602.py) for reference

I notice that it has command addresses for the following

```py
#flags for display entry mode
LCD_ENTRYRIGHT = 0x00
LCD_ENTRYLEFT = 0x02
LCD_ENTRYSHIFTINCREMENT = 0x01
LCD_ENTRYSHIFTDECREMENT = 0x00

#flags for display/cursor shift
LCD_DISPLAYMOVE = 0x08
LCD_CURSORMOVE = 0x00
LCD_MOVERIGHT = 0x04
LCD_MOVELEFT = 0x00
```

What I'm struggling with is if I have characters at positions `0,15` and `1,15`, how do I scroll this to the left?

What I'm aiming for is the characters to scroll to the left, in the hope of simply outputting a large piece of text per line and scrolling it.

What I've written

```py
import RGB1602
import Rpi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

lcd = RGB1602.RGB1602(16,2)

# SET COLOURS...

lcd.clear()
lcd.setCursor(0,0)
lcd.printout("      abc")
time.sleep(1)
lcd.command(0x04) # also tried 0x00
```

The "abc" does not move to the left, and finding documentation for this has only come up with the Ardiuino examples, not the Pi or Pico examples

Comment: Looking at the [reference](https://support.newhavendisplay.com/hc/en-us/article_attachments/4414498095511/AiP31068.pdf) of the controller chip, it seems that the command for "Cursor or Display Shift " is selected by setting bit 4 to 1, Then you use bit 3 to select between cursor (0) or display (1). Finally with bit 2, you choose direction: left (0) or right (1). In terms of that library, it would be a bitwise-or of `LCD_CURSORSHIFT`, `LCD_DISPLAYMOVE` and one of `LCD_MOVERIGHT` or `LCD_MOVELEFT`. If you want a magic number, that would be `0x1C` or `0x18`.

Comment: Thank you! It took me a few mins to unpick that as I'm rather new to hardware engineering but it now makes sense to me!